# Oracle sqldveloper view date and tora difference

Tags: oracle

If I try a query as

select * from hr.employees

by sqldeveloper I have an output where the field HIRE_DATE is display so:

21-GIU-07

The data format is in according of the land (Italy)

If I use  Tora or Toad (an old version) for the query the same row and the same field is display as

HIRE_DATE   2007-06-21 00:00:00

I am not undestand why there is time value in the field HIRE_DATE. In the example is 0 but I have found table where the time is set.

Why Tora/Toad show the time too and not in sqldeveloper ?

Thanks in advance anyone wants to answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter called NLS_DATE_FORMAT which specifies the default format for date data type.

The NLS_DATE_FORMAT has an order of overriding precedence, and tool specific NLS paramter settings will override it. That is the reason why two different tools has different outputs.

This is the most usual order of overriding precendence :

1. NLS_DATE_FORMAT is in the database initialization parameters, will be overriden by,
2. Settings of OS environment variable on the client machine, will be overriden by,
3. NLS parameter setting at session level with ALTER SESSION statements, will be overriden by,
4. to_date and to_char functions at the sql statement level.

Having said all that, in your situation, you need to check the NLS_DATE_FORMAT in both the tools.

Last but most important, check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119) and learn more about the NLS_DATE_FORMAT.